# how to improve performance of Tchart in real-time plotting?

Tags: c#, teechart

I am developing an application which has minimum one tchart with 4 fastlines in it . maximum number of tcharts are 16 depending on few criteria.each fastline contains different sample numbers in different cases. here is the problem now. If I have sample number less than 200-250. then I can see the graph is being plotted real-time. now as the sample number increases the delay goes so long in plotting the graph. so let's say if we have 1000 samples for each fasline then total of 4000 samples in chart. and there can be maximum 16 charts like this. I noticed that delay is highly dependent on number of samples fastline contains and number of fastlines in the chart. 
I already made changes regarding autorepaint = false. I have chart1.autorepaint = false
series1.autorepaint = false and also series 2 , 3, 4. 
each time I add a value in fastline , I have to manually do chart1.refresh() which takes so much time again as it refreshes all the 4 fastlines in it.
Delay can also be related to series1.add(),
but I am not sure.
Is there anything I can do to avoid the delays ?

Here is the code I am using .

```
    public void PlotActualValuesUpToSampleNumber(int SampleNumber)
     {      
            int DataPoint;
            Chart1.AutoRepaint = false;
            for (DataPoint = LastActualSamplePlotted + 1; DataPoint <= SampleNumber; DataPoint ++ )
            {

                    if (Imp.ThisSampleContainsFault[ChannelNumber, DataPoint])
                    {

                        Chart1.Panel.Gradient.Visible = false;
                        Chart1.Panel.Color = Imp.ChartBackgroundColorIfFault;

                    }

                    Series4.Add(Imp.ActualValue[ChannelNumber, DataPoint], "", Color.Yellow);

                   LastActualSamplePlotted ++;

            }
            Chart1.Refresh();
            Chart1.AutoRepaint = true;               
     }
```

Is there anything I can do to avoid the delays?
I already referred to these links.
http://www.teechart.net/reference/articles/VCLRealtime.htm http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?p=47388 http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?t=5127 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977423/performance-issue-with-tchart

but no success.

Comment: I have also tried doing series4.repaint() instead of doing the whole chart1.refresh() but no output !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance is mainly affected by the amount of data the chart has to handle. Different code solutions and environments may also be pretty influential here. So my suggestions are:

1. Have you tried injecting data arrays directly into the series as the second example Sandra posted [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?p=47388#p47388)? This is the same principle as in the VCL [Real-time Charting](http://www.teechart.net/reference/articles/VCLRealtime.htm) article.
2. have you tried the Direct 2D version of TeeChart? You can find a white paper regarding its performance [here](http://www.steema.com/entry/37/NEW_Release_Digital_Signal_Processing_with_TeeChart_for_.NET).
3. I'd strongly recommend you to check the examples at the sections below in the features demo available at TeeChart's program group.

*All Features\Welcome !\Chart styles\Standard\Fast Line*

*All Features\Welcome !\Speed*

If you still don't get the results you expected please [send us](http://www.steema.net/upload/) a simple example project we can run "as-is" to reproduce the problem here.

Comment: I tried going for option 1. but no success ! Is there anyway I can just the paint one series without refreshing the whole chart to view the changes in the series values?

Comment: There's Series' RefreshSeries() and Repaint() methods. Have you tried using them? What about the other options I suggested?

Comment: I checked options 1 and 3 , no success ! I sent a example project with instructions , but no reply yet.

Comment: I also tried doing series4.refreshseries() and series4.repaint() instead of chart.refresh() but the chart does not show live changes in the values of series4. I can only see it if I refresh the chart.So, only repainting and refreshing the series does not reflect changes in the graph.

Comment: Option 2 , Direct 2D version, I want to try it but I am not able to compile the example program and they do not have tchart class. I am working on conversion of delphi code to C# . The Delphi application show the changes real time and somehow c# library methods are not working as they are supposed to

Comment: Am I supposed to do Chart1.Graphics3D = new Graphics3DDirect2D(Chart1.Chart); for option2 ?

Comment: @saumilpatel sorry, since we didn't receive any reply from you we didn't search for the attached project. I tried to use it now but I can't because it uses Microsoft.Office.Core assembly which I don't have. Hence the project can't find VSConstants. Could you elaborate a simpler project I can run as is?

Comment: @saumilpatel Regarding Direct 2D you should do the same as in the D2D demo shipped with the TeeChart installation:       
      Graphics3DDirect2D D2D = new Graphics3DDirect2D(tChart.Chart);
      tChart.Graphics3D = D2D;
      tChart.Graphics3D.BufferStyle = BufferStyle.None;
Does the demo work fine at your end?

Comment: I modified the project and it should run now.I sent the project and about Direct2d , my application now does not draw graph1. I see the red cross in the windows form when it compiles.

Comment: @saumilpatel I'm still getting the "The name 'VSConstants' does not exist in the current context" error. Looks like I need Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0 assembly (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vsconstants%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which doesn't exist in my VS2010 Ultimate either. Regarding D2D, does this occur with the demo shipped with the installer?

Comment: Ok I removed all the references related to vsconstants. and sent it . That does not happen with demo shipped. :|

Comment: @saumilpatel Thanks, solved those errors but can not run the project as I still get an error with TfrmHardware class at QAS.cs: "The type initializer for 'Hardware.Units.Hardware' threw an exception.". How should we solve that? Comments here are getting long. If I'm not wrong, you are a Steema registered customer. You may want to bring the issue to our forums for registered customers: http://www.teechart.net/support/index.php. Please make a reference to this question to put everything in context. Thanks in advance.