# series of tchart insert Array?

Tags: c#, teechart

I'm sorry I did not get English.
Did you give an example for the meaning of question
give a series of teechart the array?
Graphs, one per array gonna draw

Array[0] > series[0]
     series[1]

Array[1] >series[0]

Array[2] >series[0]
series[1]

Answer (score 1):

Please see my [reply here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124751/how-to-improve-performance-of-tchart-in-real-time-plotting/14124983#14124983). There I suggested how series can be directly populated from arrays.

Comment: I already had a solution in a different way. Thank you for your interest !

Comment: You're welcome. In that case it would have helped and saved us time if you posted your solution here as well.